# Convert OLTP database to OLAP Datawarehouse

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5Qjm.jpg).  Basically I need help to convert that **OLTP Model** to **Data Warehouse** in order to be used for further **OLAP Cubes**. I understand well the difference between the Star Schema and the Snowflake Schema in design , but can't figure out what tables to keep in and what tables to exclude . ***Note**: This **OLTP Model** is devoted in the Retail field and it must answer questions like the following:

- How many customers are spending more over time? Less over time? Describe these customers.

  - Of those customers who are spending more over time, which categories are growing at a faster rate?
  - Of those customers who are spending less over time, with which categories are they becoming less engaged?
  - Which demographic factors (e.g. household size, presence of children, income) appear to affect customer spend? Engagement with certain categories?
  - Is there evidence to suggest that direct marketing improves overall engagement?

So , based on the above questions as I read on various data-warehouse sites and blogs , I must keep some tables that will be useful and merge other tables as possible . If anyone can help I can share the dataset description for each table and the function of each column , I would be thankful for advices and participation .

Comment: Is this for work/personal project, or homework?

Comment: hello @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister this is for **Personal Project** ? thanks for contribution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in this case I suggest you to adopt a star schema. the  transaction_data table obviously will be you reference to construct your fact table because it contains 'measures' like quantity,sales_value and other numeric attributes , the fact table also will contain substitution-keys of dimensions tables like Time, Product, Customer,demographic, etc.

Comment: thanks @Yassine LAADIDI , I actually started in that design process , but can't figure out if it is right or not . So please send me an email on that address that you accept to revise that model with me. coderevening@outlook.com THANKS ALOT

Comment: your welcome @CoderEvening, email sent.

Comment: Hi @Yassine LAADIDI , Could you please contact me on this address coder_evening@outlook.com ? Thanks yassine cause there was a misuse of the first e-mail address.

Comment: @CoderEvening Ok